How to open a java package while running jmeter scripts from JMeter?
I am running Jmeter scripts via Maven & Jenkins. The script needs parallel controller plugin for execution. It throws the below error during execution.
module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @366647c2
How to add the below JVM argument to pom.xml to fix this issue?
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-8552009 (build 17.0.9+8-LTS)
com.blazemeter:jmeter-parallel:0.12
com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:3.8.0




You can pass the property to mvn command like:
MAVEN_OPTS="--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED" && mvn clean install

In POM you can use jMeterProcessJVMSettings section like:
<configuration>
    <jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
        <arguments>
            <argument>--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED</argument>
        </arguments>
    </jMeterProcessJVMSettings>
</configuration>

More information:

Configuring the jvm that the jmeter process runs in
How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin


I am getting the error shown in the screenshot attached to the question on adding this option to the pom.xml. Can you please help to resolve it?

Thanks for your input. Fixed it by setting it to the JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS variable.

Setting the JVM options to the JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable fixes this issue.
